# JBoss EAP 5.1 Server not using Windows Network Setting

Tags: web-services, networking, settings, jboss5.x

I'm trying to call a web service from my application. My system is protected with a Firewall and I'm using a Proxy to access any external URL/internet access. The application is running on JBoss EAP 5.1 server. The application fails to write to the service URL with IO Exception: 'Could not transmit message'.

However, when I'm trying to access the service URL with IE/Firefox, it's opening. Although the XML response I'm receiving from Browser states a generic error - 'invalid request parameters...', which is quite obvious. Because I'm not sending a proper request XML from Browser.

I'm really confused with this disparity. I used to believe that JBoss will pick up standard windows network settings, but in my case it is not.

My code is as follows:

```
String strUrl = "http://theurlgoeshere";
String requestXml = "<request></request>";
String wsResponse="";
SOAPConnection conn = null;

try {               
MessageFactory msgFac = MessageFactory.newInstance();
MimeHeaders mh = new MimeHeaders();
mh.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");

log.info("Request Xml:" + requestXml );
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(requestXml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
SOAPMessage reqMsg = msgFac.createMessage(mh, is);

SOAPConnectionFactory conFac = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
conn = conFac.createConnection();

SOAPMessage repMsg = conn.call(reqMsg, strUrl);     
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
repMsg.writeTo(out);            
wsResponse = new String(out.toByteArray());
}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted few days back. Basically I am using HttpURLConnection now to add proxy setting in the java code itself while making the Webservice call. Just closing this question, since my query is solved.

Will update the new code, if anyone needs.